# JPA named query to get size of a collection

Tags: java, jpa, named

I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
class Relation{

@ManyToOne
private User user;

//some other fields

...
}
```

The user entity has a collection of other entities:

```
@Entity
class User {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private Collection<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
}

//some other fields

}
```

Is it possible to write a named query in the Relation entity which gives me the users which have more than 2 addresses...?
like:

`@NamedQuery("SELECT m from Membership m where m.otherfield = ?1 AND m.user.addresses > 2")`

in other words, how can i get the size of this entity with a named query?

thx

Comment: why not use `SELECT COUNT(m) from ....`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JPQL query SIZE function can be used to get size of collection. It takes path to the collection as argument and returns number of elements.